# How can I get the averages for all the departments in the year?

Tags: sql

In the query below I'm getting the average for each department 
from each month in the year. I'm trying to get the average for all 
departments from the year.

For example for May in 2014 i would get 2.675 average, 
        june 2014 would be 2.532.

How can I get the averages for all the departments in the year for each month?

Here is my query, that I get averages from each department:

```
SELECT employeedept,YEAR_cse,csedept_name,
        SUM(January) as January,SUM(February) as February,SUM(March) as March,SUM(April) as April
        ,SUM(May) as May,SUM(June) as June,SUM(July) as July,SUM(August) as August
        ,SUM(September) as September,SUM(October) as October,SUM(November) as November,SUM(December) as December
        FROM (SELECT employeedept,
    (ROUND(AVG(case when rating1>0 THEN CAST(rating1 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) +
        ROUND(AVG(case when rating2>0 THEN CAST(rating2 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) +
        ROUND(AVG(case when rating3>0 THEN CAST(rating3 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) +
        ROUND(AVG(case when rating4>0 THEN CAST(rating4 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) +
        ROUND(AVG(case when rating5>0 THEN CAST(rating5 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2)) /5 as AG,
        count(*) as 'totalstars',month_cse= datename(month,execoffice_date),YEAR_cse =YEAR(execoffice_date)
        FROM CSEReduxResponses  
        Where YEAR(execoffice_date) = 2014


        group by employeedept,month(execoffice_date),YEAR(execoffice_date),DATENAME(month,execoffice_date)

      )
    AS r   
JOIN CSEReduxDepts d

ON d.csedept_id = r.employeedept
AND YEAR_cse is NOT NULL
PIVOT( SUM(AG)
    FOR [month_cse] IN (
        [January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July],[August], [September],[October],[November],[December]
        )) AS pvt 
Group BY     employeedept,YEAR_cse,csedept_name
```

I made a http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d97e/1 with dummy data.

Comment: Check the edits to my answer. It should give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What if you get the sum in a outer select like below `group by year_case`. See your modified fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d97e/17.

```
select  EMPLOYEEDEPT,
YEAR_CSE,
CSEDEPT_NAME,
((sum(isnull(JANUARY,0)) +
sum(isnull(FEBRUARY,0)) +
sum(isnull(MARCH,0)) +
....
sum(isnull(DECEMBER,0))) / 12) as total_AVG_for_year
from
(
 //your inner main query
) X
group by YEAR_CSE,employeedept,csedept_name
```

Comment: @user3591637, if you have seen the fiddle at all .. I didn't do a average rather just a sum of all. To get the `avg` just divide by 12. Anyways, edited both my answer and fiddle. take a look again (new fiddle link included in edited answer).

Answer (score 0):

I edited your fiddle example to include a few uses of grouping() and a having clause. Also cleaned up numbers that weren't being selected from the group by clause. This allowed us to get the total from the aggregate functions with easier-to-read code. Check out the example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d97e/48).

```
    SELECT employeedept,YEAR_cse,COALESCE(csedept_name,'All Depts') AS csedept_name,
        SUM(January) as January,SUM(February) as February,SUM(March) as March,SUM(April) as April
        ,SUM(May) as May,SUM(June) as June,SUM(July) as July,SUM(August) as August
        ,SUM(September) as September,SUM(October) as October,SUM(November) as November
        ,SUM(December) as December
        FROM (
          SELECT 
              employeedept,
              (ROUND(AVG(case when rating1>0 THEN CAST(rating1 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) +
               ROUND(AVG(case when rating2>0 THEN CAST(rating2 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) +
               ROUND(AVG(case when rating3>0 THEN CAST(rating3 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) +
               ROUND(AVG(case when rating4>0 THEN CAST(rating4 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) +
               ROUND(AVG(case when rating5>0 THEN CAST(rating5 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2)) /5 as AG,
              count(*) as 'totalstars'
              ,month_cse=datename(month,execoffice_date)
              ,YEAR_cse =YEAR(execoffice_date)
              , grouping(DATENAME(month,execoffice_date)) as MonthRollup
              , grouping(YEAR(execoffice_date)) as YearRollup
              , grouping(employeedept) as EmployeeDeptRollup
          FROM CSEReduxResponses    
          Where YEAR(execoffice_date) = 2014
          group by rollup(DATENAME(month,execoffice_date),YEAR(execoffice_date),employeedept)
          having (1^grouping(DATENAME(month,execoffice_date)))&(1^grouping(YEAR(execoffice_date))) = 1
      )
    AS r   
left JOIN CSEReduxDepts d

ON d.csedept_id = r.employeedept
AND YEAR_cse is NOT NULL
PIVOT( SUM(AG)
    FOR [month_cse] IN (
        [January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July],[August], [September],[October],[November],[December]
        )) AS pvt 
Group BY     employeedept,YEAR_cse,csedept_name
order by case when employeedept is null then 2 else 1 end, csedept_name
```

Comment: thanks but I don't think you understood the question I have made some edit to it, the results should be 1 row that shows the months averages for that year

Comment: @user3591637: Indeed. Sorry for the mis-read. I have a solution in the works, was working on order by clause for the final query when SQLFiddle went down. Will update soon.